# version wcf for backward compatibility

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I have a service which has a following method:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface TestContract
{
  [OperationContract]
  void GetTest(Test test);
}
```

Now in my new service contract Type `Test` has been moved to different namespace with new name `TestNew`
This is my new service contract:

```
 public interface TestContract
{
  [OperationContract]
  void GetTest(TestNew test);
}
```

How do I implement the service without breaking the existing client.  That means achieve backward compatibility without having the existing clients  update their service references.

Basically, the type of the parameter changed, which is a breaking change. Since, I have both old and new client now. Is there any way I could change my service contract without having to change the service reference of both old and new client? I was thinking intercepting somewhere during the serialization/deserialization of parameter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making Backward-Compatible WCF Services](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826017/making-backward-compatible-wcf-services)

Answer (score 0):

You could define `TestNow` as a subclass (and `KnownType` of `Test`) and not change the method signature, or you can add a new `Action` by either changing the name of the method (leaving the old) or using the `Name` property on the `OperationContract` attribute.

The more common approach for a breaking change is to just define a new endpoint.  E.g.: http://foo/someservice/2014-05 for the first version and http://foo/someservice/2015-10 for the new one.

Comment: Basically, the type of the `parameter` changed, which is a breaking change. Since, I have both old and new client now. Is there any way I could  change my service contract without having to change the service reference of both old and new client? I was thinking intercepting somewhere during the serialization/deserialization of parameter

Comment: Er... yes?  I listed three methods which do not require changing configs in any way.  (subclass old datacontract, add as new method, or add backcompat method with same action).

Comment: The reason is I cannot subclass old data contract and i need it in same action

Comment: Subclassing the old data contract lets you keep the same action.  You just check the parameter type to see if they are calling with the update or not.  `void foo(Base p) { var d = p as Derived; if (d != null) { /* new contract */ } else { /* old contract } }`